# Как назвать промежуточное api?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, веб-программирование, api

Приложение на nodejs и react состоит из следующих частей:

APP - интерфейс на реакте

Middleware - промежуточная апишка, собирает данные из источников и кладет их в БД

API - основная апишка, которая забирает данные из БД и отдает в APP

Мне кажется, что название Middleware не совсем корректное для данного промежуточного апи

Может быть есть какое-либо общепринятое название для таких случаев?

Comment: Ну чаще всего промежуточные обработчики так и называются Middleware. Т.е. когда клиента делает вызов, затем этот запрос обрабатывает какая-то функция и только потом функция АПИ. Если я всё правильно понял